# How to get id from ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an html response coming from an AJAX request and now i want to get id from html response and then i want to compare it with string.

This is my response:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.List" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<div id="categorylist">
<c:forEach items="${childCategorylist}" var="childcategory">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <c:if test="${categoryinlist != 0}">

        <a href="#" onclick=getChildCategory(${childcategory.id})>${childcategory.categoryName}</a>
            <div id="childCategory${childcategory.id}">kl</div></c:if>

            </li>
    </ul>
</c:forEach></div>
```

Comment: ID of which element ?

Comment: where ajax function  located?

Comment: ajax function is in another jsp

Comment: <div id="categorylist"> i want this id

Comment: show your ajax function?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var Id;
 function getChildCategory(id) {
  Id=id;
  url="/childCategory?Id="+id;
  getXmlHttpObjectResponse(url,"Post",null,"TEXT","handlecategoryeInfoResponse");
 }
 function handlecategoryeInfoResponse(response){

      
    
  /* document.getElementById("childCategory"+Id).innerHTML=response; */
 
 }
 </script>

Comment: @javed, What are the parameters to find the `id` ? Is it the parent element  or something ?

Comment: yes , actully  want i want to do here is i am calling childcategory from ajax if any child not having another child then i want to get id of productlist otherwise i want id of categorylist .